# Making a histogram out of groupby() data using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a histogram of data out of the `groupby` method in Pandas.

Here's the piece of code that I wrote:

```py
df['Total Revenue'] = df['Quantity'] * df['UnitPrice']
df.groupby('Country')['Total Revenue'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

which produces this output:

```py
Country
United Kingdom          8187806.364
Netherlands              284661.540
EIRE                     263276.820
Germany                  221698.210
France                   197403.900
Australia                137077.270
Switzerland               56385.350
Spain                     54774.580
Belgium                   40910.960
Sweden                    36595.910
```

What steps can I take to make a histogram out of this data?

Comment: Do you mean a bar plot of the summed values? `df.plot(kind='bar')` after `df = df.groupby...` then `plt.show()`

Comment: You can also do `df.hist`.